# embed render table in action button in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to embed render table in action button. 
I want, when i click my action button, my table should come as pop up in render table output.

```
tabPanel("2017",tags$div(id="PublicationPi2017", style="width:50%;height:400px;")
                          ,deliverChart(div_id = "PublicationPi2017"),
                          actionButton("go","View All")
                         ),

server<-output$go<-renderDataTable(Publication)
```

*Publication* is my data det.
After this code i am able to get action button with name "View All", but on clicking it no popup or table is showing.

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible example with some inbuilt dataset that i can use to reproduce your issue and help? If i understand, you want to have an action but that should display a table in a popup, is it?

Comment: yes... i want an action button which display in popup.

Comment: Did you try this? https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/